# How to strip double quote (") characters from sequence

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence of sequences and each sequence is similar to the following:

("9990999" "43" "ROADWAY" "MORRISON, VAN X DMD" "43  ROADWAY" "SOMETHINGTON" "XA" "00000" "501" "18050" "2500" "1180" "14370" "0")

clojure-csv won't help me here, because it -- as it should -- quotes fields with embedded commas. I want pipe-delimited output without quotes around each field, some of which contain embedded commas.

I have looked at a number of ways to remove the double quote characters including the following, but the quotes stay put.

`(filter (fn [x] (not (= (str (first (str x))) (str (first (str \")))))) d1)`

where d1 is the sequence above.

In addition to an answer, I am more interested in a pointer to documentation. I have been playing with this but to no avail.

Comment: Are the double quotes part of the actual data or are they just delimiters that represent a string?

Comment: To answer your comment, I edited the OP.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand you have a sequence of strings. Clojure provides a very specific toString implementation for sequences, you can see it [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L1759).

If you do `(str d1)` or simply type `d1` in repl and press enter you'll see more or less what you typed: sequence of strings (String is printed as sequence of characters in double quotes).

Now if you want to concatenate all the string you can do this:

```
(apply str d1)
```

If you want to print it separated with commas you could do this:

```
(apply str (interpose "," d1))
```

To output is CSV format I would recommend to use [clojure-csv](https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv).

Finally if you simply want to print the list but without the double quotes around strings you could do this:

```
(print d1)
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT1** (update due to changes in the question):

This can easily be achieved with:

```
(apply str (interpose "|" d1))
```

Please don't pay attention to double quotes around the entire result if you `print` it or `spit` it into a file you won't see them, this is just how Clojure prints string [readably](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L1766).

Alternatively if you have multiple sequences like that that you want to output at once you can still use clojure-csv but with different separator:

```
(ns csv-test.core
  (:require [clojure-csv.core :as csv]))

(def d1 (list "9990999" "43" "ROADWAY" "MORRISON, VAN X DMD" "43 ROADWAY" "SOMETHINGTON" "XA" "00000" "501" "18050" "2500" "1180" "14370" "0"))
(print (csv/write-csv [d1]  :delimiter "|"))
;;prints:
;;9990999|43|ROADWAY|MORRISON, VAN X DMD|43 ROADWAY|SOMETHINGTON|XA|00000|501|18050|2500|1180|14370|0
```

Comment: I might add that [`pr`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pr) is the method printing the data to the REPL, which produces [`read`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read)-able output, whereas using [`print`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/print) like you suggest is supposed to give more human-readable output, which is why it doesn't include the quotes.

Comment: @DaoWen thanks for `pr` I couldn't remember the name of the function.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. At some point, I remembered the display in REPL part of a string versus what gets written out, but when I saw quotes around the output .csv fields, I remembered that for any of my data that can contain commas, like joint names or addresses, I had to switch gears and hand write out an Informix default pipe delimited file.